# How to fill polygon with multiple equally different colors (3, 4, 5 and more colors) - Code needed (Symbology - Geometry generator)

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers, style, color-ramp

I need to make a map with politics of the European Union and found that the numbers of members from some parties are equal, for example:

Netherlands : EPP - 6, S&D - 6, Renew Europe - 6

I tried searching on the internet how to divide polygon into different colors and found only this : [Filling polygon with 2 different colours representing 2 different sets of data using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384898/filling-polygon-with-2-different-colours-representing-2-different-sets-of-data-u), which mentions only how to divide a polygon in 2 equal colors.

I do not have 2 datasets, I just need to edit the name of the colors within the legend.

I would like to know how should that code be modified in order to divide a polygon in 3 / 4 / 5 or more equal colors. Or if that code can not be modified, how to code what I need from 0 because I am clueless. I tried to play around with the code but nothing worked out.

Here you have Austria as an example divided in 2 equal colors ( not from the map I want to make ) . I need to divide a polygon just like Austria in 3 equal colors and if it possible divide other polygons in 4 / 5 or more colors : [image]

Here is what I would like to achieve in QGIS through coding in Symbology - Geometry generator and not digitizing ( the images are edited in Paint ) :

3 equally sized polygons :

[image]

4 equally sized polygons :

[image]

5 equally sized polygons :

[image]

6 equally sized polygons :

[image]

Etc. and more than 6 , the code should be similar from here on

19 equally sized polygons with 4 lines north-south and 4 line west-east

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to divide a polygon in 3 / 4 / 5 colors or more just like in this post : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384898/filling-polygon-with-2-different-colours-representing-2-different-sets-of-data-u . I tried changing the code to 
I tried changing $geometry to $boundary , $bounds etc. I also changed the values from 100000 to 10000000 more or less . I tried to make a second line which could go east - west besides north south  .

Comment: I do not know what else should be done . I try to achieve something visually something like this within a polygon : https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44740/coloring-an-n-by-n-grid-with-four-colors .  You have a square with 4 more equally sized and colored squares .

Comment: I try to add another line from north to south which divides a polygon like Austria in 3 equally sized regions and another line from west to east which could divide the Austria polygon in 6 regions if I have 2 lines north south , or 4 regions if I have only 1 line north south .

Comment: Since the data seems fairly static, you could pre-process it like in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321021/splitting-polygon-into-equal-area-polygons-using-qgis)

Comment: Thank you so much for the link ! Unfortunately that would not work , because I have around 50 polygons and I only need to edit somwhere between 5 - 10 with coding . Using those proccesses mentioned in the link will affect all my work ( It could probably work on my 5 - 10 polygons I need to edit and the rest until 50 will be wrong ) . Is not there any way to do it in Symbology --> Geometry generator ?

Comment: I really don't understand the only difference with your other [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/449199/how-to-fill-polygon-with-multiple-unequally-different-colors-and-label-3-4-5) is that the values are equal instead of unequal ?

Comment: This Question with Equal values was made before the one with Unequal values . I had thought about the one with Unequal values afterwards . I saw that the code mentioned from the post of Unequal values would work on the post on Equal values . I just have another question here .  Is it possible to create multiple lines on the x and y axis taking a simple example the screenshot where Austria is divided in 4 Equal polygons above ? And how could you multiply that code so you add more lines like in the screenshot where Austria is divided in 19 Equal polygons above? Thank you very much ! Best Regards

Comment: Please my other Question got closed ( https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/449199/filling-polygon-with-multiple-unequally-different-colors-and-label-3-4-5-and ) , even though I did not manage to do the last part with Labeling . I edited it ( I do not know if you are able to see the edits - I added 4 screenshots ) that managed to do something about the Labeling part , but I am stuck . Could you please check if it is possible my last 4 uploaded screenshots and tell where the mistake is so I could do the Labeling part too ? Thank you very much !