# Manually modify the legend symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers, style, color-ramp

In legend how can you make the polygon symbol which has multiple colors on the map appear with more colors, because in New Print Layout it appears with just 1 color which is not true (Symbology - Geometry generator).

Symbology of the polygon (left - red, right - blue):

[image]

Map with Default Legend from Symbology - Geometry Generator:

[image]

Map with Edited Legend from Symbology - Geometry Generator in Photoshop:

[image]

Is it possible to do something about that or you just have to use Paint / Photoshop to edit that polygon symbol within the legend?

Comment: How did you create the symbology with two partes (left/right of vertical line): what expression do you use?

Comment: I used no expression in QGIS . I saved the map as PNG , uploaded it in Photoshop , zoomed on the symbol I wanted to edit from the legend , used a ruler from the real world in air not glued to the PC screen to figure out where the half would be then made a square with " Polygonal Lasso Tool " , then copying the color I needed with Eyedropper Tool and finally coloring it with the Brush tool . Maybe you could achieve the same result in Paint . I was wondering if someone could achieve this thing in QGIS without relying on Photoshop or Paint .

Comment: This is by no way a GIS approach, this is purely a graphical approach. I don't understand why you speak about "Geometry Generator" when you don't need it at all. Please edit and update your question to make clear what you have and where you're stuck.

Comment: As you can see Austria is divided in 2 colors and that was made possible due to coding in Geometry Generator . Problem is Geometry Generator recognises just 1 color and not 2 and in Legend you have just 1 color and I do not know how to edit it .

Comment: OK, then why don't you provide the code you used in Geometry genrator? That was what I was asking about...

Comment: I made a similar post before this one here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/449199/how-to-fill-polygon-with-multiple-unequally-different-colors-and-label-3-4-5 . Maybe somebody will have an answer .

Comment: The code is here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384898/filling-polygon-with-2-different-colours-representing-2-different-sets-of-data-u . For some reason I can not post the code as a comment . I changed the values twice from 100000 to 1000000

Comment: Did you try my expression from the solution below? It should work for any polygon layer, splitting it in half.

Comment: I posted my answer down below with a screenshot . It still does not work . Maybe it is because of the QGIS version ? Thank you !

Comment: I used QGIS 3.28, so yes, I guess you should use the current QGIS version to get the legend as you want it.

Comment: Ýou were right . The current QGIS version 3.28 does not have any problems with the legend : https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYOL9.png . Also thank you so much for the suggestion how to paste the link of an image in a comment !

Comment: Problem is , QGIS 3.28 for some reason has problems with labels ( same QGIS 3.20 ) , I had to move some labels on the map and they simply dissapear in Print Layout and that is why I use QGIS 3.12 because I do not have any problems with the labels in Print Layout , but with the legend . There is no way I could edit the colors of the legend by dividing them in QGIS 3.12 is not there ?

Comment: I would encourage you to continue with 3.28 and create another post here with a question about what goes wrong with labels. For sure QGIS 3.28 can handle this.

Comment: I upvoted it and accepted it as an answer . Thank you very much !

Comment: Please also be aware of this comment by @Erik https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384898/filling-polygon-with-2-different-colours-representing-2-different-sets-of-data-u#comment630378_384898

Comment: Yes , I posted in one of the comments above . Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a pixel based graphical software approach, what you want to do can be realized much easier using QGIS expressions with Geoemtry generator. Then also the legend will appear correctly (see screenshot at the bottom).

[image]

In addition to the default style (single symbol - yellow, in my case), define a second style of type Geometry generator for the left half (blue, in my case), on top of the yellow style. Use this expression to create such a style:

```
intersection (
    $geometry,
    extrude( 
        make_line(
            make_point(x_min($geometry), y_min($geometry)),
            make_point(x_min($geometry), y_max($geometry))
        ),
        (x_max($geometry)-x_min($geometry))/2,
        0
    )
)
```

*Legend appears correctly:*
[image]